# Windows 7 menu and label are black

Tags: windows-7

I get those black background on labels, and menu are black too.

It does this randomly after it comes back from sleep.

The only way I found to make it disapear is to reboot, which I don't like.

Some spec :

- Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit
- Ati driver latest version (11.7)
- Intel Core i5 2400
- 8gb DDR3
- Amd Radeon HD 6950 2gb

I would ilke to find the source or a simple fix without reboot.

If you need more information feel free to ask.

[image: img]

Comment: How much memory do you have, and how big is your page file (c:\pagefile.sys it is hidden, so you may have to make hidden files visible). Do you have a spare USB flash drive?

Comment: @KCotreau, No USB flash drive, 8 gb DDR3 with Intel i5 2400 and 8 gb page file allocated. It's set to auto actually.

Comment: OK, I was thinking you might be low on system resources. I have to wonder if your video memory might have a problem.

Comment: @KCotreau, It seems to be more a fail of Windows than hardware, since on reboot everything is fine.

Comment: I have seen these black icons many times, and it is usually related to memory somehow. Of course, when you reboot, it would work if it is memory since it has been flushed.

Comment: @KCotreau, true for memory flush on reboot, but with that much ram, and nothing running except Chrome, I'm not really near out memory, in fact even with a VM and a game running I didn't manage to fill it.

Comment: "related to memory somehow" could involve the memory being corrupt rather running out of it.

Comment: @Windos, would testing the memory be a good thing ?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt...

Comment: As far as filling it, you are assuming that your video memory does not have a problem. Try testing it with these: http://majorgeeks.com/Video_Memory_Stress_Test__d5896.html http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en